# Batch program won't loop

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

This program won't work, it won't even loop itself. It just close itself after seting `value` and `value2` (he is setting them correctly, and it should pass at least one if, and even if it don't pass, he should go to start again.

```
@echo OFF
set file1=file path
set file2=file path
set file3=file path
:start
FOR /f "tokens=2-3 delims=$" %%a in (%file1%) do set value=%%a%%b
FOR /f "tokens=2-3 delims=$" %%a in (%file2%) do set value2=%%a%%b
echo %value% %value2%
    IF %value2% GTR %value% GOTO true
    IF %value1% GTR %value2% GOTO true2
    GOTO start

:true
type nul > %file3%
type %file2% >> %file3% 
GOTO start

:true2
type nul > %file3%
type %file1% >> %file3% 
GOTO start
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you start it directly from the cmd with `@echo ON` so you can debugg it properly without it closing. Then maybe try using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) when checking the values.

Comment: %value1% is never set?

Comment: @ManoDestra Good eye! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you give us no indication of the contents or names of the files, we're in guesswork territory.

If you are running the batch from the prompt, you may see a "syntax error" message. If you are running it by clicking it from the desktop, the window will close - you'll be unable to read the error message.

In all probability, what is happening is that either `value` or `value2` is **not** being set by the code. If this is the case, the `if` statement involving those variables will generate a syntax error.

change

```
echo %value% %value2%
IF %value2% GTR %value% GOTO true
IF %value1% GTR %value2% GOTO true2
GOTO start
```

to

```
echo value1=%value% value2=%value2%
pause
IF %value2% GTR %value% GOTO true
pause
IF %value1% GTR %value2% GOTO true2
pause
GOTO start
```

to see what the variables are being set to. I'd guess they're empty.

Comment: I didn't touch it and it started working now. Really weird, but thank you! :)